# Feed me config setup

Tags: plugin-feedme, api, guzzle

I am trying to do an import of course data into craft but I am running into a problem with the feed me config (feed-me.php).
He is the curl request I want to run and this works and outputs the data I need

```
     curl -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -u API key :x -passsword PUT -d '<request><programme><code><course-code></code></programme></request>'https://pathto/search.xml
```

I can authenticate using the API key and password using the settings below

```
'feedOptions' => [
        '7' => [
            'feedUrl' => 'https://pathto/search.xml',
            'requestOptions' => [
                'auth' => [
                    'api key', 'password'
                ],
```

I don't know how to do the query in the config,I have looked at the Guzzle options and you can do a PUT to GET but I don't know what the syntax is the do this in the feedme.php config or even if this is possible.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that this feed uses Basic Auth to authorize the request? I'm not quite sure what the `:x` in your example curl request means?